# Xcode 4.4 + MacRuby = "macruby.h not found" (OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion)

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos, macruby, osx-mountain-lion

I get the following error when trying to run a basic "Hello world" application in MacRuby on Xcode 4.4 in OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion:

> "macruby.h not found"

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Probably one of those famous errors Apple enjoys skipping over when releasing major updates and a new OS..

But seriously, I would try a clean install if the one on there isn't already

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try adding `/Library/Frameworks` to the framework search path. Make sure you tick the checkbox as well.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Adding to search path did not fix issue. Which checkbox are you referring to in your answer? Thanks.

Comment: @user456584 - Edited my answer with a screenshot.

Comment: @BoA what does the checkbox do?

Comment: @wprater Sorry for the late reply. It makes recursive I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is add a symbolic link in Xcode default searching path for MacRuby.

Open Terminal and insert command:

`sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/MacRuby.framework \ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/MacRuby.framework`